# Edge based binarization

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I am trying to implement the edge based binarization algorithm that was written in the research paper ["Automatic License Plate Recognition Using Deep Learning Technique"](https://scholarworks.uttyler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1029&context=ee_grad) but i as i implemented it i get the final image all black and can not find the problem.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def edge_based_binarization(image):
    edge_image = cv2.Canny(image, 0, 255)
    binary_image = np.zeros(shape=image.shape)
    Hblocks = 10
    Vblocks = 5

    blockH = np.floor(image.shape[0] * 1.0 / Vblocks)
    blockH = np.array(blockH, dtype=np.uint8)
    blockW = np.floor(image.shape[1] * 1.0 / Hblocks)
    blockW = np.array(blockW, dtype=np.uint8)

    for r in range(Vblocks):
        for c in range(Hblocks):
            r0 = r * blockH + 1
            c0 = c * blockW + 1

            imgblock = image[r0 : r0 + blockH, c0 : c0 + blockW]
            edgeblock = edge_image[r0 : r0 + blockH, c0 : c0 + blockW]

            t = find_threshold(imgblock, edgeblock)
            if(np.all(imgblock < t)):
                 binary_image[r0 : r0 + blockH, c0 : c0 + blockW] = 1
            else:
                 binary_image[r0 : r0 + blockH, c0 : c0 + blockW] = 0

    binary_image = np.array(binary_image, dtype=np.uint8)
    return binary_image

def find_threshold(imgblock,edgeblock):
    t1 = [ ]
    for r in range(3,imgblock.shape[0] - 2):
        for c in range(3,imgblock.shape[1] - 2):
            if(edgeblock[r,c] == 255 and edgeblock[r,c-1] == 0 and edgeblock[r,c+1] == 0):
                m = min(imgblock[r,c-2], imgblock[r,c+2])
                if m < 128:
                    t2 = np.mean(imgblock[r,c-2 : c+2]) * 1.0
                    t1.append(t2)                    
            if(edgeblock[r,c] == 255 and edgeblock[r-1,c] == 0 and edgeblock[r+1,c] == 0):
                m = min(imgblock[r-2,c], imgblock[r+2,c])
                if m < 128:
                    t2 = np.mean(imgblock[r-2 : r+2,c]) * 1.0
                    t1.append(t2)

    if len(t1) == 0:
        t = 0
    else:
        t = np.mean(t1) - np.std(t1)

    return t

img = cv2.imread("test1.jpg")
cv2.imshow("Orig", img)
img = edge_based_binarization(img)

cv2.imshow("Edge", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Code given in the paper
[find threshold function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fLB4.png)
[edge based binarization function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRIvO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing the given code with what has been stated in the paper, I must say that the appended implementation in the paper is wrong.

I didn't search for another proof, but from what was said in the paper, the algorithm binarizes an image by estimating a local threshold at edge pixels within a 10x5 pixel region and later assembling the whole binary image from these rather small patches.

The given implementation instead slices the image into 10 vertical and 5 horizontal blocks, resulting in much larger regions.

```
Hblocks = 10
Vblocks = 5

blockH = np.floor(image.shape[0] * 1.0 / Vblocks)
blockH = np.array(blockH, dtype=np.uint8)
blockW = np.floor(image.shape[1] * 1.0 / Hblocks)
blockW = np.array(blockW, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Since the algorithm in general is correct, it actually only requires a minor fix for the block sizes and a small adjustment to the range sizes when estimating the threshold.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2
import numpy as np
from sys import argv
from math import floor


def edge_based_binarization(image):
    edge_image = cv2.Canny(image, 0, 255)
    cv2.imwrite("edge.png", edge_image)
    binary_image = np.zeros(shape=image.shape)

    # Fix block sizes
    blockWidth = 10
    blockHeight = 5

    verticalBlocks = floor(image.shape[0] / blockHeight)
    horizontalBlocks = floor(image.shape[1] / blockWidth)

    for r in range(verticalBlocks):
        for c in range(horizontalBlocks):
            # Fix 1 pixel border
            r0 = r * blockHeight
            c0 = c * blockWidth

            imgblock = image[r0: r0 + blockHeight, c0: c0 + blockWidth]
            edgeblock = edge_image[r0: r0 + blockHeight, c0: c0 + blockWidth]

            t = find_threshold(imgblock, edgeblock)
            if(np.all(imgblock > t)):
                binary_image[r0: r0 + blockHeight, c0: c0 + blockWidth] = 0
            else:
                 binary_image[r0: r0 + blockHeight, c0: c0 + blockWidth] = 1

    return binary_image * 255.0


def find_threshold(imgblock, edgeblock):
    t1 = []
    # Adjust range indices
    # Otherwise it would result in an empty range for the 5px height
    for r in range(2, imgblock.shape[0] - 2):
        for c in range(2, imgblock.shape[1] - 2):
            if(edgeblock[r, c] == 255 and edgeblock[r, c - 1] == 0 and edgeblock[r, c + 1] == 0):
                m = min(imgblock[r, c - 2], imgblock[r, c + 2])
                if m < 128:
                    t2 = np.mean(imgblock[r, c - 2: c + 2])
                    t1.append(t2)
            if(edgeblock[r, c] == 255 and edgeblock[r - 1, c] == 0 and edgeblock[r + 1, c] == 0):
                m = min(imgblock[r - 2, c], imgblock[r + 2, c])
                if m < 128:
                    t2 = np.mean(imgblock[r - 2: r + 2, c])
                    t1.append(t2)

    if len(t1) == 0:
        t = 0
    else:
        t = np.mean(t1) - np.std(t1)

    return t

img = cv2.imread(argv[1])
cv2.imshow("Orig", img)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bin_img = edge_based_binarization(img)

cv2.imshow("Edge", bin_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Your correction worked greatly but i think the algorithm implementation in the paper itself is different from the pseudo code stated since the binarized image isn't as shown in the paper or any where nearly a recognizable image.

Comment: As I said, I didn't search for a reference but only relied on the information provided in the paper. Binarization worked well with my test images, but I can't tell whether the described algorithm is correct. Anyways, I'm glad I could help!